# How to animate stuff with animate.css and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, animate.css

I have following code pieces

**HTML**

```
<ul id="test">
    <li class="a">1</li>
    <li class="b">2</li>
    <li class="c">3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="test2">
    <li data-prod="a" class="animated">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>        
    </li>
    <li data-prod="b" class="animated hide">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div> 
    </li>
    <li data-prod="c" class="animated hide">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul#test > li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#test {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#test2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#test2 > li {
    background: yellow;
    width: 350px;
    height: 600px;
    /* transition: height 0.3s ease, width 0.2s ease;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -30px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-right: -50px;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

And this **jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#test li').on('click', function () {

        var className = $(this).attr('class');
        $('#test2 > li').each(function () {

            var prodName = $(this).data('prod');


            if (prodName == className) {

                $('#test2 > li').removeClass('bounceInRight').addClass('bounceOutRight');
                $this = $(this);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log(this);
                    $('#test2 > li').addClass('hide')
                    $this.removeClass('hide bounceOutRight').addClass('bounceInRight');
                }, 400);


            }
        });
    })
});
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rkau7b9o/4/)**

I have few questions

1. For each click on `li` of `ul` with id `#test` it animates the
   appropriate `li` of `ul` that has id `#test2`. How do I animate each div in `li`s  as
   `fadeInTop` (animate.css)  one after another without
   using classes and ids (just using tag selectors) once the `li` has completed the animation.
2. Is there a better way of doing what i have done with jquery with better performance. I have added this part of question in [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87148/coding-animations-with-css-and-js-and-code-performance)

Comment: Have you taken a look at the in-built jquery functions, like [hide](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp), [fadeIn and  fadeOut](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp)?

Comment: @Phoenix Yea, But i want to do this with animate.css and jquery doesnt have fadeIn from top kind of animation

Comment: Try this if you after animations with effects and no css files -- http://julian.com/research/velocity/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a callback for the animation. Without removing and adding class you can't repeat an animation.

```js
               $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#test li').on('click', function () {

            var className = $(this).attr('class');
            $('#test2 > li').each(function () {

                var prodName = $(this).data('prod');


                if (prodName == className) {

                    $('#test2 > li').removeClass('bounceInRight').addClass('bounceOutRight');
                    $this = $(this);
                    $this.find('div').removeClass('fadeInDown');
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        console.log(this);
                        $('#test2 > li').addClass('hide')
                        $this.removeClass('hide bounceOutRight').addClass('bounceInRight');
                    }, 400);

                    
                }
            });
          
        })
        
        $('#test2 li').on('oanimationend animationend webkitAnimationEnd', function() { 
            $(this).find('div').each(function(i){
               var $this = $(this);
                setTimeout(function(){
                  $this.addClass('animated fadeInDown')
                },i*500);
                
            })
        });
    });
```

```css
    ul#test > li {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #test {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    #test2 {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    #test2 > li {
        background: yellow;
        width: 350px;
        height: 600px;
        /* transition: height 0.3s ease, width 0.2s ease;*/
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-top: -30px;
        padding-top: 30px;
        margin-right: -50px;
    }
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
    ul#test2 > li div {  padding: 5px; transform: translate3d(0,-2000px,0)}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.6/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul id="test">
  <li class="a">1</li>
  <li class="b">2</li>
  <li class="c">3</li>
</ul>
<ul id="test2">
  <li data-prod="a" class="animated hide">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </li>
  <li data-prod="b" class="animated hide">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </li>
  <li data-prod="c" class="animated hide">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you :) This helps me a lot. i want to animate those divs one after one in the order of 1, 2, 3. Could you please help me with that